# Get list of objects with one object from m2m field pointing to self

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have `Business` model with m2m field holds branches. Some businesses have branches some don't.

```
class Business(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    branches = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

And I want to get list of ordered (by `order` field) businesses with only one (top) branch from the chain (if business has branches).

For example let's the first letter means belonging to the chain, and the number means the sort order:

```
AA-0
AB-1
AC-2
AD-3
B-4
C-5
D-6
E-7
FA-8
FB-9
FC-10
```

`A...` and `F...` objects have branches, `B`, `C`, `E` and `D` don't.

The list I want to get is:

```
AA, B, C, D, E, FA
```

In other words I want to exclude all the branches of any business from the final list except one branch. I need a presence of business in the list but without branches.

How I did it with a double loop:

```
object_list = Business.objects.all().order_by('order')
object_list_no_branches = []
for obj in object_list:
    found = False
    for obj_inner in object_list_no_branches:
        found = obj_inner.branches.filter(pk=obj.pk).exists()
        if found:
            break
    if not found:
        object_list_no_branches.append(obj)
```

But obviously looping is not the technique I need.

Is it possible to do it with Django ORM or PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is AA-0, AB-1, etc. Output of what? Order is an integer field and does not support this format.

Comment: Simple representation of real business objects. The first letter means belonging to the chain, and the number means the sort order. It's just a model to show what I mean.

Comment: So, given one business object, you want to query it and it should return branches satisfying those requirements. is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy thing to answer without just suggesting a library.  You are talking about recursion, and this is a tricky task in programming, especially if you get too deep.  You can do this many levels deep with [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) though.  The documentation explains it pretty good, and that is found [here](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).  It is pretty easy to implement though.

Comment: MPTT has parent and children objects, but in my case it's not a hierarchical structure. All branches are equal. Businesses don't have headquarter (parent) and branches (children).

Comment: I guess I assumed you wanted something you didn't.  Would setting symmetrical to false be what you need?  I'm unclear about how you need these relationships to be ordered.

Comment: I mean like how it is used here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: I'm not sure that setting symmetrical to false will solve the problem. Please look at the updated question. I need to exclude from `Business.objects.all().order_by('order')` businesses from `branches` except one for each business.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you need now, and I can't think how to easily do that without multiple queries, and even then, it looks like it would be tricky.  I'll keep it in the back of my head and get back to you if an answer comes to me, but I'm going to delete this answer after a while so it doesn't confuse people, as it is the completely wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I asked this in hope that there is an easy way to do it via Django ORM.

Comment: There is certainly a combination of Q objects that will work.  In case you aren't familiar, here they are:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should put that representation information inside your model.

```
class Business(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    chain_id = models.CharFieldField(max_length = '1') 
    chain_second_letter = models.CharFieldField(max_length = '1')
    branches = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    def representation:
        return '%s%s-%s' % (chain_id,chain_second_letter,order)
```

Then, given a business object, you can do like this to get info about minimum for each first letter:

```
from django.db.models import Min
l = Business.branches.all().values('chain_id').annotate(Min('order')):
## this returns something like 
##[{'chain_id':'A',order__min:'1'},
##{'chain_id':'B',order__min:'0'},etc...]
```

Looks file the output you want its:

```
final = []
for obj in l:
   business = Business.objects.get(chain_id = obj['chain_id'],order = obj['order_min'])

   final.append('%s%s' % (business.chain_id,business.chain_second_letter))
```

This last loop is horribly slow if you have many business to go through. Ceirtainlly there are smarter ways to do this.